# rsyslog forwarding msg using template format to remote server

Tags: linux, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I want to send logs from 2 client servers to a single remote server.
The client config :

```
  ...
  module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")    # Polling every 10 secondes
  ...
  if $syslogtag == 'apache' then {
    action(type="omfwd" Target="192.168.0.10" Port="514" Protocol="udp" )
    & stop
  }
  ...
  input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/httpd/my_apache_log"
      Tag="apache"
      Severity="info"
      Facility="local7")
   ...
```

The server config :

```
  ...
  # Provides UDP syslog reception
  $ModLoad imudp
  $UDPServerRun 514
  ...
  if $syslogtag == 'apache' and $syslogseverity-text == 'info' then {
    /my_path/my_apache_log
    & stop
  }
  ...
```

These configs work like a charm.

Now, I want to use `template format` to customize the logs.
So, in the client config, I change the config like this :

```
  ...
  module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")    # Polling every 10 secondes
  ...
  template (name="MyTemplate" type="list") {
        property(name="hostname")
        constant(value="', ")
        property(name="msg")
        constant(value="\n")
  }
  ...
  if $syslogtag == 'apache' then {
    action(type="omfwd" Target="192.168.0.10" Port="514" Protocol="udp" template="MyTemplate")
    & stop
  }
  ...
  input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/httpd/my_apache_log"
      Tag="apache"
      Severity="info"
      Facility="local7")
   ...
```

If I run the following command `rsyslogd -N1`, I don't get any errors, but I don't have any more logs on the remote server.

Why ?

Comment: would you try `template (name="MyTemplate" type="list") {
        property(name="hostname")
        constant(value=",'")
        property(name="msg")
        constant(value="'\n")
  }`?

Comment: ... and also try `rsyslogd -N2` if can see more verbose output if any.

Comment: @αғsнιη I tried your template with no more success. `rsyslogd -N2` does not show more information. Instead of `type="list"`, I also tried `type="string"`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you specify the template when receiving the logs? And did you check, that the properties you're checking for are still in the message? Otherwise you may be receiving the logs but they're just not being logged because of the conditional.

Comment: @eDonkey, well, instead of setting the template on the sender,  I set it on the receiver. And it works like that. But I didn't understand why it's not ok when I define it on the sender.

Comment: Rsyslog expects the logs to be in a specific format, if it isn't in that format, the message is dropped. Therefore you have to specify the format (template) in which you expect the received messages to be in.

Comment: To help other users coming across the same problem, you may want to create an answer and mark your question solved.